# Read the first two lines from a text file named "file1.txt" Write the two lines read from "file1.txt" to a new file "file2.txt"

Tags: python

I need to read the first two lines from a text file named "file1.txt"
Write the two lines read from "file1.txt" to a new file called "file2.txt"
Read "file2.txt" and Print the contents

```
a=open("file1.txt")
NumberofLines = 2
with open("file2.txt","w") as b:
    for i in range (NumberofLines):
        line = a.readline()
        b.write(line + "/n")
print(b)
a.close()
b.close()
```

But this is not working and I can't find the error. please help

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. "Please help" [is not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) here. If you "cannot find the error", then please first [make sure you know basic techniques for finding errors](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), try to apply them, and explain what you still don't understand. It is not useful to tell us that "this is not working"; **what happens** when you run the code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: There are multiple problems here. 1. See where the assignment says "Read "file2.txt" and Print the contents"? What part of the code is intended to read that file? 2. Please use `with` blocks to open both files; when you do so, do not use `.close` afterwards - the point of `with` is that it will take care of that for you. 3. What do you expect `"/n"` to mean? Please look at it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
NumberofLines = 2

# open the 2 files in the same time
# NOTE: when we use with there is no need for file.close()
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt','w') as f2:
    for _ in range(NumberofLines):
        # read the line from f1 and write it into f2
        # NOTE: no need for '\n' because the line we read will have it
        f2.write(f1.readline())

# open file2 and read its content
with open('file2.txt','r') as f3:
    print(f3.read())
```